# How to prevent AndroidView from recomposition in jetpack

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, recompose

I have two AndroidView. And I need change place and state in one AndroidView but not recompose another.
Then state change ChangableAndroidView NotChangableAndroidView recompose too.

How to prevent recompose NotChangableAndroidView then ChangableAndroidView change her state?

```
@Composable
fun TwoAndroidView(){
Column{
  if(isFirst){
    NotChangableAndroidView()
    ChangableAndroidView()
  }else{
    ChangableAndroidView
    NotChangableAndroidView
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called `key` and it could be used for your case:

```
@Composable
fun TwoAndroidViews(isFirst: Boolean) {
    Column {
        if (isFirst) {
            KeyedAndroidView(key = "notChangable", content = { NotChangableAndroidView() })
            KeyedAndroidView(key = "changable", content = { ChangableAndroidView() })
        } else {
            KeyedAndroidView(key = "changable", content = { ChangableAndroidView() })
            KeyedAndroidView(key = "notChangable", content = { NotChangableAndroidView() })
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun KeyedAndroidView(key: Any, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    key(key) {
        content()
    }
}
```

This approach uses the `key` composable function to help Compose track and optimize the recompositions of `NotChangableAndroidView` and `ChangableAndroidView` based on their keys. If the composables are identical in structure and only their data or state changes, Compose can optimize the recomposition process more effectively. However, changing the order of composables still involves recomposition to reflect the updated UI accurately.